# SQL Alias CASE with Dynamic Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create an alias for the CASE statement by joining two strings. One of the strings is passed through a variable and I'm not able to figure how to do it. Below is an example of what I want to do. I'd much appreciate your help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FEATURE_SET]
    @topic NVARCHAR(100) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CASE 
           WHEN colA = @topic AND colB = 'abc' 
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
        END AS CONCAT(@topic, 'outcome')
    FROM
        dbo.table
END
```

The above query keeps throwing an error "incorrect syntax".

Much appreciate your help.

Comment: SQL Server is declarative by design.  What you are looking for can only be accomplished with Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you would require Dynamic SQL.   SQL Server does not support macro substitution.

**Example**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FEATURE_SET]
    @topic NVARCHAR(100) 
AS 
BEGIN
    Declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = replace(N'
    SELECT [getTopicoutcome] = CASE WHEN colA = ''getTopic'' AND colB = ''abc'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     FROM  dbo.table
    ','getTopic',@Topic)

    --Print @SQL
    Exec(@SQL)
END
```

Comment: Thanks, John. I did not know that and I learned something new.

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal Always happy to help.   Learning something new is the fun part... that's why I'm such a fan of this site.   :)